# How to Restrict Zip code on the checkout page Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, magento2.4.5

We have several zip code in Stores configuration that is only allow for the delivery so how can i put the validation on the checkout page , if someone enter the postcode which is not available on the stores configuration then they can not able to go to the payment step on the checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom shipping rules on the checkout page and cart page. Sample code on **magento/module-usps**

### Step 1:

- Adding shipping validation rule component to checkout page **checkout_index_index.xml**

Sample code on vendor/magento/module-usps/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml:7

```
<item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="step-config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="shipping-rates-validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="usps-rates-validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Usps/js/view/shipping-rates-validation</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

### Step 2 define component and model.

**view/shipping-rates-validation.js**

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rates-validator',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rates-validation-rules',
    '../model/shipping-rates-validator',
    '../model/shipping-rates-validation-rules'
], function (
    Component,
    defaultShippingRatesValidator,
    defaultShippingRatesValidationRules,
    uspsShippingRatesValidator,
    uspsShippingRatesValidationRules
) {
    'use strict';

    defaultShippingRatesValidator.registerValidator('usps', uspsShippingRatesValidator);
    defaultShippingRatesValidationRules.registerRules('usps', uspsShippingRatesValidationRules);

    return Component;
});
```

**model/shipping-rates-validator.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mageUtils',
    './shipping-rates-validation-rules',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($, utils, validationRules, $t) {
    'use strict';

    var checkoutConfig = window.checkoutConfig;

    return {
        validationErrors: [],

        /**
         * @param {Object} address
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        validate: function (address) {
            var rules = validationRules.getRules(),
                self = this;


            if (!this.validationErrors.length) {
                if (address['postcode'] == checkoutConfig.notAllowedPostCode) {
                     self.validationErrors.push("Your postcode is not allowed");
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    };
});
```

More required files (model/shipping-rates-validation-rules.js)

### Step 3:

- Adding a custom checkout config provider, which adding **notAllowedPostCode** to checkoutConfig.

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="yourvendor_yourmodule_checkout_config_provider" xsi:type="object">YourVendor\YourModule\Model\YourConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

- **YourVendor\YourModule\Model\YourConfigProvider**

```
// @TODO Check sample code on Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider
```